# Is there a way to find out whether a view controller is popped off the navigation stack?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Im trying to detect when a view controller is popped off the navigation stack, in a way that i have a reference to the controller on the next layer of the stack (currently working with Swift 3). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UINavigationController` has a property `viewControllers` that contains an array of the view controllers currently on the stack. You could get the array of view controllers and then fetch the next-to-last view controller from that array:

```
guard let navController = self.navigationController else {
  print("We are not part of a navigation stack!")
  return
}
let stack = navController.viewControllers
let stackCount = stackCount
if stackCount > 1 {
  let nextVC = viewControllers[stackCount - 2]
  //nextVC now contains the view controller one down from the current VC
} else {
  //We are the root view controller
}
```

Comment: Ah, got it working, thanks. Just figured this could also be done by calling willmovetoparent and than accessing the viewcontrollers array.

Comment: I don't believe the parent/child relationship of navigation controllers and their children is documented, so I wouldn't count on it. The implementation details could change out from under you in some future OS release and break your code.

Comment: Agree, I've implemented your solution and added it to my code snippets. Thanks!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem you should accept it. Upvoting is optional but appreciated. :)